# Customizing Google AdSense "Privacy and Cookie Settings" popup

Tags: google-adsense, eu-cookie-law

I am using [Google AdSense's default GDPR consent message](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10961068?hl=en). Yet after clicking the consent button, users get this annoying permanent popup on the left bottom corner:

[image]

Is it possible to move this div to a custom defined place? (e.g I have a settings button where it should be possible for users also to manage their cookie preferences.) I am aware that [this popup is required to be there by EU law](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121040/does-google-adsense-require-a-privacy-politcy-and-cookie-notification-popup), I just want to move it somewhere where it won't take so much attention.

Comment: A still very relevant question because this particular button on the bottom left corner, in combination with the floating/sticky footer ads on 1000+ px screens causes the Chrome and Firefox browsers to freeze after a user reaches the end of the page (the moment this banner should appear and fold out) ... Extremely annoying, specially since the Adsense devs refuse to fix the conflict!